# Reading DNA text file using JAVA

Tags: java, bufferedreader

> I want to read the DNA text file of bacteria using java  i made this
>   code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
// implements a simplified version of "type" command provided in Windows given
// a text file name(s) as argument, it prints the content of the text file(s) on console
class Type {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\mohamed\\Downloads\\dataset_2_6.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
}
```

> but the output is null 
>   , it work when using small text file

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this code.Maybe you put the wrong path to your BufferedReader object.

Comment: May I know what is the size of the text file when your program fails?

Comment: Could you please give the stack trace?

Comment: Here is the link of the text file 
https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lessons/2/Vibrio_cholerae.txt

Comment: Path is correct and i change the text file name to dataset_2_6.txt before run the program

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a fix to your question, but changing `\\ ` to `File.separator` will make your program compatible between other OSs. It may be that you are using it on an OS that uses `/` instead.